# Swift synchronise network request

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

Im getting user's input and creating CoreData entity for it, and put in to the tableView, but before i need to designate some properties for entity by making a couple network requests. And there is a problem. First entity is always nil (and create a empty cell for table view) but if i save context and open app again - here it is, entity is ok. If i create second (and so on) entity it works fine. Its also seems like table always create am empty cell for start and then delete it and create proper cell…
I cant get why completion handlers doesn't work properly and network requests makes asynchronously. Please help me to understand.

Creation metod starts in `textFieldShouldReturn`

```
 import UIKit
 import CoreData

 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
    lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Word> = {

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Word> = Word.fetchRequest()
        let createdSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: false)
        let idSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: false)

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [createdSort, idSort]

        var fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: AppDelegate.viewContext,
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
            cacheName: nil)

        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        return fetchedResultsController
    }()

    private var hasWords: Bool {
        guard let fetchedObjects = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects else { return false }
        return fetchedObjects.count > 0
    }

    let creator = WordManager.shared

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        managedObjectContext = AppDelegate.viewContext
        fetchWords()

        updateView()
    }

    func updateView() {
        tableView.isHidden = !hasWords
        messageLabel.isHidden = hasWords
    }
    ............

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        guard let managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext else { return false }
        guard let title = textField.text, !title.isEmpty, !title.hasPrefix(" ") else {
            showAllert(title: "Warning!", message: "Title may not to be nil!")
            return false
        }

        let word = Word(context: managedObjectContext)
        guard let fetchedWordsCount = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count else { return false }

        creator.createWord(title: title, counter: fetchedWordsCount, word: word)
        self.updateView()

        textField.text = nil

        return true
    }


    func fetchWords() {
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Cant fetch words. Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Creating entity

```
import CoreData
import UIKit

class WordManager {
    static var shared = WordManager()
    private init() {}

    private var api = DictionaryAPI()
    private var api2 = MeaningAPI()

    func createWord(title: String, counter: Int, word: Word) {

        self.api.fetch(word: title, completion: { translation in
            self.api2.fetchTranscription(word: title, completion: { transcription in

                word.id = Int16(counter) + 1
                word.title = title
                word.translation = translation
                word.transcription = "[\(transcription)]"
                word.created = NSDate()
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Nothing interesting in tableView

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections else { return 0 }
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let section = fetchedResultsController.sections?[section] else { return 0 }
    return section.numberOfObjects
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mainCell", for: indexPath) as! MainCell

    let word = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    cell.configure(with: word)

    return cell
}
```

}

Configure cell method

```
    func configure(with word: Word) {

        titleField.text = word.title
        translationField.text = word.translation
        transcriptionLabel.text = word.transcription
        totalCounter.text = "\(word.showCounter)"
        correctCounter.text = "\(word.correctCounter)"
        wrongCounter.text = "\(word.wrongCounter)"
}
```

Fetched Results Delegate

```
extension ViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
    updateView()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case .delete:
        guard let indexPath = indexPath else { return }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    case .insert:
        guard let indexPath = newIndexPath else { return }
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    case .move:
        guard let indexPath = indexPath else { return }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        guard let newIndexPath = newIndexPath else { return }
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .fade)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem:

- The data you have in core data is not in a state that is ready to be shown in the app.
- The `NSFetchedResultsController` just happens to pick this data and shows it in the app.

## Approach:

- When a user creates a records, the user wants to see the changes immediately in the app and shouldn't have to wait for the app to update in the server to see the changes. So a user would still be able to create records even when there is no network connectivity.
- Create a child context from view context
- Use a background thread to upload to the server and when update records on to the child context.
- Save child context only when the data is in a consistent state.
- `NSFetchedResultsController` should be using the view context so would be unaware of the child context records.
- When you save the child context, the `NSFetchedResultsController` would pick these records.

Comment: The thing is i don't need poor records in CoreData.